# Prevent browser from opening context menu

Tags: javascript

I have a element which is initially hidden by css.

```
<span class="error-span">Some text</span>
<button id="button">Zoom</button>
```

And I have a JavaScript function which will show me the text as long as a button is pressed. When I move away from the button the text is hidden again.

This is fine, however on Safari on iPhone the event opens the menu after a while (Where you can search, copy etc.)

Is there any way to prevent this?

JavaScript:

```
$('#button').on('touchstart mouseenter',  function (e) {
        $( ".error-span" ).show();
    });

    $('#button').on('mouseleave touchmove click', function (e) {
        $( ".error-span" ).hide();
        request
    });
```

EDIT: Using `oncontextmenu="return false;"` however, when I keep pressing the button longer than a few seconds, then it seems that it freezes (Because it gets selected) and I can only hide the element by clicking somewhere.
I have also tried using an img and span instead of the button and this

```
html,body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

without success.

Comment: I think doing a simple `e.preventDefault(); return false;` in a `contextmenu` event callback will be sufficient. What are you trying to do with this no-op statement `request`, though?

Comment: Try adding this CSS to the elements: `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`.

Comment: @Xufox : `oncontextmenu="return false;"`
Did work for me. Thank you.

I want this particular text to be shown when the user hovers over the button, similar to a tooltip. (If that answers your question.)
However when I keep the button pressed for longer than a few seconds I have to click somewhere else to make hide again. (Seems that that the button gets selected) I have tried 
`html,body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}`

Comment: @ibsof You could try `<input type="button" />` instead of `<button></button>`. Maybe the text won’t get selected with that element. Another option is to use CSS `user-select: none;` or a prefixed version of that.